# jQuery ajax data.d undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamics-crm

I am trying to get CRM data using the Ajax call. Data is being returned with 'd' and 'result' properties but I can't get it on client side. It says ajaxdata.d is undefined.

**A sample Ajax call:**

```
var context = Xrm.Page.context;
var serverUrl = context.getClientUrl();
var ODATA_ENDPOINT = context.prependOrgName("/xRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc");

var filter = "?&$select=cc_TypeID,cc_customentityId,cc_anotherAttribute&$filter=cc_TypeID eq '2'";

var odataUri = ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/cc_customentitySet" + filter;

console.log("odataUri: " + odataUri);

//Asynchronous AJAX function to Retrieve a CRM record using OData
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: odataUri,
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.            
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    success: function (ajaxdata, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
        //console.log("cc_campaignSynch.htm > ready > $.ajax success: " + data);

        debugger;

    },
    error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("cc_campaignSynch.htm > ready > $.ajax error: " + XmlHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

**Snapshot of data returned:**

[image]

**Updated Snapshot (JSON.parse used):**

[image]

Comment: don't you need to JSON.parse(ajaxdata) before you can access the properties in this way?

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest, jQuery should deal with that automatically.

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest was correct (see the updated image above). However, I thought what Andy suggested already. So confusion is why the jQuery magic didn't work here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be something of nothing, but try changing "datatype" to "dataType"

Comment: wonderful Jonny :). This was the reason the jQuery was not converting the result into json.

Answer (score 0):

To force jQuery *magic* work and recognize the data type, try to send the response back with `HEADER: "Content-Type: application/json"`.

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` was already included in the call.

Comment: yes, you told the server your data `contentType` (not important in this case) and that you're expecting back (`dataType`) data in json, That's ok. But if you won't specify the `dataType` and send back your response with header `"Content-Type: application/json"` from the server, jQuery will automatically recognize the data type (because you not forced `dataType` option) and parse the data like `json`

Comment: dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))